# Attempting to output the coordinates of point structs c++

Tags: c++, function, struct

I have defined the following struct as a template for me to store x and y coordinates for point:

```
typedef struct point {
    int x_coordinate, y_coordinate;
};
```

I have also defined the following function:

```
point* get_neighbours(point p) {
    point neighbours[4] = {};
    point left_neighbour, right_neighbour, upper_neighbour, lower_neighbour;

    left_neighbour.x_coordinate = p.x_coordinate - 1;
    left_neighbour.y_coordinate = p.y_coordinate;
    neighbours[0] = left_neighbour;

    right_neighbour.x_coordinate = p.x_coordinate + 1; 
    right_neighbour.y_coordinate = p.y_coordinate;
    neighbours[1] = right_neighbour;

    upper_neighbour.x_coordinate = p.x_coordinate ;
    upper_neighbour.y_coordinate = p.y_coordinate+1;
    neighbours[2] = upper_neighbour;

    lower_neighbour.x_coordinate = p.x_coordinate;
    lower_neighbour.y_coordinate = p.y_coordinate - 1;
    neighbours[3] = lower_neighbour;
    return neighbours;
}
```

However, when I execute the following code:

```
point the_point; 
the_point.x_coordinate=3; 
the_point.y_coordinate=3; 
point* neighbours=get_neighbours(the_point); 
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cout << neighbours[i].x_coordinate << " " << neighbours[i].y_coordinate << "\n";
    }
```

I get the following output:

```
 2 3
 -858993460 0
 -858993460 0
 14677568 14678244
```

Any ideas why.

Comment: You need to read and **learn a lot more about C++** and its [memory management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management) & [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization). Spend a week reading, first about [Programming in C++](http://stroustrup.com/Programming/)

Comment: BTW, you should consider using [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and declare `std::vector<point> get_neighbors(point p);` at least. Probably, `point` should be some `class`  with a `std::vector<point> get_neighbors();` member function (i.e. method).

Comment: Thank you very much. Already on chapter 4!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line

```
point neighbours[4] = {};
```

to this

```
point* neighbours = new point[4];
```

It must be allocated on the heap, because yours is allocated on function's stack so it will be loss on function exit.

Comment: So then what is the difference between allocating on a a function's stack and allocating on the heap. Is the heap the stack for the entire program?

Comment: No, the main has it's own stack. Heap is the room for dynamic allocated one.

Comment: @TeereraiMarange: We cannot teach you C++ basics here. You need to learn them elsewhere.

Comment: Use a `std::vector` or `std::array` and return it. There is no need dynamic allocation here.